# Deploying an ec2 instance without using aws secret access key and aws access key id

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, aws-access-policy

My workstation and server are both ***RHEL ec2 instances*** and
whenever I run the command:-

> knife ec2 server create
>   -r “role[----------]”
>   -I ami-XXXXXXXX
>   -f t2.small 
>   -S knife
>   -i ~/.ssh/XXXXXXXXXXX.ppk –ssh-user ec2-user –region us-east-1
>   -Z us-east-1a

I am getting the error as
ERROR: You did not provide a valid ‘AWS Access Key Id’ value.
ERROR: You did not provide a valid ‘AWS Secret Access Key’ value.

Nor I want to use the secret access key and access key id and neither I want to save them on the workstation.
Is there any other way to deploy a new ec2 instance(node) ,perhaps using IAM role .
thank you

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK we don't support role credentials in `knife-ec2`, you'll have to use something else to start the machine (like the `aws` command line). Once created, you can use `knife bootstrap` to set up Chef.

Comment: is there any other way to create an ec2 instance with knife-ec2 plugin, recipe or knife.rb.
i am a novice in chef and currently working on infra creation through chef.